# switch multiple images on click

Tags: javascript, image, onclick

I have the code to switch an image back and forth and it works fine.  However, I was wondering if there was a way to rewrite the script so I can use it in multiple places.  This is my code currently:

```
    function swaparrows(obj) {
        var x=document.images

            if (x[0].src.match('images/editloadout.png')) {
                x[0].src="images/editloadoutopen.png";
            }

            else if (x[0].src.match('editloadoutopen.png')) {
                x[0].src="images/editloadout.png";
            }
    }

<img src="images/editloadout.png" onclick="swaparrows()" />
```

which works for this one specific instance only.  I would like it to work in multiple places with different pictures entirely.

Comment: It depends on how you want to store the additional image data.

Comment: Why are you requesting all the documents images (`var x = document.images`) and not using the `obj` in your function parameters?

Comment: use css and a target?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the two images in to the swap function, and use the actual clicked object's src:

```
function swaparrows(obj, i1, i2) {
  var src = obj.getAttribute('src');

  if (src.match(i1))
    obj.setAttribute('src', i2);
  else
    obj.setAttribute('src', i1);
}
```

where the HTML is:

```
<img src="images/editloadout.png" 
  onclick="swaparrows(this, 'images/editloadout.png', 'editloadoutopen.png')" />
```

example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/GoEBF

Answer (score 0):

So you could use a case switch and decide based on the sender ID
Reference:http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp
example:

```
 function swaparrows(idTag) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(idTag);
        switch(idTag){
           case("editLoadout"):                
            if (ele.src.match('images/editloadout.png')) {
                ele.src="images/editloadoutopen.png";
            }    
            else if (ele.src.match('editloadoutopen.png')) {
                ele.src="images/editloadout.png";
            }
          break;
          case("button2"):
            if (ele.src.match('images/button2.png')) {

                ele.src="images/button2open.png";
            }

            else if (ele.src.match('button2open.png')) {
                ele.src="images/button2.png";
            }
          break;

        }
    }

<img id="editLoadout" src="images/editloadout.png" onclick="swaparrows('editLoadout')" />

<img id="button2" src="images/button2.png" onclick="swaparrows('button2')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use css and let javascript do more important stuff?

replace the `background-color` with `background-image` or whatever

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Switch</title>
<style>
.i{
 width:32px;line-height:32px;
 display:block;float:left;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:white;
}
.i:target{
 background-color:green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a class="i" id="a" href="#a">a</a>
<a class="i" id="b" href="#b">b</a>
<a class="i" id="c" href="#c">c</a>
<a class="i" id="d" href="#d">d</a>
<a class="i" id="e" href="#e">e</a>
</body>
</html>
```

another approach is to set a js var with the current selected item and toggle the class of that.if you want an example just ask.any other questions just ask.

.. there are many ways to to what you want, your approach is not a good one.